# Register ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I would like to create connection between table 1 and table 3 when I create new user. What I have to do? Probably later I will need update this and there is my another question how update Roles?

1.

[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

There you have this standard control:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplicationpomoc.Account
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        }

        protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);



            string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(continueUrl))
            {
                continueUrl = "~/";
            }
            Response.Redirect(continueUrl);
        }

    }
}


<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplicationpomoc.Account.Register" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="RegisterUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="RegisterUserWizardStep" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <h2>
                        Create a New Account
                    </h2>
                    <p>
                        Use the form below to create a new account.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%= Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
                    </p>
                    <span class="failureNotification">
                        <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </span>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="RegisterUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                         ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
                    <div class="accountInfo">
                        <fieldset class="register">
                            <legend>Account Information</legend>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" 
                                     ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                     ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                     CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match."
                                     ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                        <p class="submitButton">
                            <asp:Button ID="CreateUserButton" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Create User" 
                                 ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <CustomNavigationTemplate>
                </CustomNavigationTemplate>
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: you already have them connected thry table 2

Comment: No. Second table is null I have data in Table 1 and Table 3 but connection is in table 2 which is empty

Comment: When you save data to role table (for a user), add record to the 2nd table.

Comment: question is how this control create user and where I should find INSERT to this and later how can I get information about role : Administratore, User, Super_User using this control lenguage.

Comment: You have to show us some code where you save, without seeing that , we can not suggest a solution

Comment: What subsystem do you use to connect to the database?

Comment: this standard control registration I added code to this.

Comment: @WiktorZychla When you create new website you have got this function in standard I`m using Express Database in my VisualStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are only suspicions but from what you write it seems that you have vague idea how the asbnetdb database is accessed. Therefore I think that you are using a built-in `SqlMembershipProvider` class - you provide the connectionstring only and the provider does the rest for you automatically.

If this is so, then probably the easiest way to assign roles to users would be to also use a builtin `SqlRoleProvider` to get an access to Roles API. This is how you configure both providers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx

Adding a user to a role is then as simple as:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole( "username", "rolename" );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx